# Remove all controls (subviews) in UITabBarViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I'm fairly new to ios programming and I encountered an issue lately. I'm trying to navigate to a selected tab of a tabbarviewcontroller programmatically. Upon entering that selected tab, remove all controls in it and repopulate it with different controls.

I managed to navigate to that selected tab programmatically, however, i'm unable to remove all the subviews.

Below are snippet of my codes..

```
- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender {
            orthoPaedicInjuryTabBarViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OrthoInjuryTabBarVC"];
            orthoPaedicInjuryTabBarViewController.selectedIndex = 2;
            [self presentViewController:orthoPaedicInjuryTabBarViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Empty Field, Step3"
                                                    message: @"Please fill up the frequency of exercises"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [self.alert show];

}




   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    Store *MyStore = [Store SharedStore];
    OrthoInjury *orthoInjury = MyStore.orthoInjury;

    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *Dob = [format stringFromDate:orthoInjury.dateOfInjury];

    self.lblDateOfInjury.text= Dob;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.typeOfExercisesList  = [Utility GetTypesOfExercisesList];

    self.pickerViewTypesOfexercises.dataSource = self;
    self.pickerViewTypesOfexercises.delegate = self;

    TherapyPhases *therapyPhases = MyStore.therapyPhases;
    self.tbxNumberOfWeeks.text = @(therapyPhases.durationWeeks).stringValue;

    if([[orthoInjury.natureOfInjury uppercaseString] isEqualToString:[@"Repetitive Strain Injury" uppercaseString]])
    {
    NSArray *subArray =  [self.view subviews];
    if([subArray count] != 0) {
        for(int i = 1 ; i < [subArray count] ; i++) {
            [[subArray objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
            /*if ([[subArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                NSLog(@"%@",[[subArray objectAtIndex:i] text]);
            }*/
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below for removing the subviews:-

```
NSMutableArray *subVws=[self.tabBarController.view.subviews mutableCopy];
[subVws performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried this and it threw me an exception with the following details.


2014-12-28 18:21:21.681 Physio[1876:523149] -[__NSArrayM removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd250f67ab0
2014-12-28 18:21:21.683 Physio[1876:523149] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd250f67ab0'
*** First throw call stack:
(